# What is the correct usage of "A is to B as C is to D"?

Tags: grammar, idioms, american-english, phrase-usage

This confused me for a long time. Are the following sentences correct? (The words "Java" and "JavaScript" below are two computer languages whose names are kind of similar but indeed very different.)

1. Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster.
2. What Java to JavaScript is like (what) ham to hamster.
3. What Java is to JavaScript is like (what) ham is to hamster.

The first one is a common joke in computer science area, but it doesn't look like a complete sentence. I always use the second or the third one, and people understood them perfectly, but I doubt if I can use them this way. What is the correct way for it and how can I use it in a sentence?

---

Update:
I wanna clarify some confusion of my question. I would like to know, if someone ask me a question like "What is the difference between Java and JavaScript?" What should I answer as a complete sentence. Is it possible I can directly answer:"Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster"?

Comment: The first version is syntactically and idiomatically fine. The second one is syntactically invalid. The third one is "valid", but it's awkward, and wouldn't be expected from a competent native speaker. What makes you think there's something wrong with the first one?

Comment: Your title uses the correct pattern and so does 1.  2 and 3 do not attempt to preserve the pattern.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I didn't say the first one is wrong, it is a common, but "something as something" is not a sentence. If somebody asks me, "What's the difference between Java and JavaScript?" It is kind of strange to answer "I think, Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster".

Comment: (4) << What Java is to JavaScript, ham is to hamster. >> is grammatical, but doesn't work as often as (1). << 15 : 35 :: 6 : 14 >> is fine if academic (and is identical in form to (1), using symbols for the word-strings 'is to' and 'as'; the words are read out when reading aloud), but 'What 15 is to 35, 6 is to 14' would be considered extremely weird.

Comment: @Jim If somebody asks me, "What's the difference between Java and JavaScript?" What do you think is the correct way for me to answer? My concern is that, "something as something" is not a complete sentence.

Comment: ... following on from your last-but-one comment, if you thought the metaphors were reasonable, you'd say 'What ham is to hamster, Java is to JavaScript.' Though if we're using words as words here, and I think we are, those words should be set off using highlight≈scare quotes say.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @FrankMi - I think you’re parsing it wrong.  The essence is not “something as something”  but rather “A is  [just] as C is.   A relates to B in the same way that C relates to D.

Comment: @Jim Oh, just notice this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @FrankMi: Okay - but I still don't understand why you don't ***like*** the first version, which as I said is both syntactically and idiomatically fine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Jim just answered my question. I thought "something as something" is not a complete sentence, so I didn't know how to use it to form a complete sentence. He told me my parsing was wrong, the essence should be "A is [just] as C is",so this IS a complete sentence. Do you agree with that?

Comment: @FrankMi: No, I don't think "A is [just] as C is" is a useful way "understanding" this particular idiomatic usage. Nobody normally says ***Men are as women*** when they mean *Men are **like** women* (and utterances like ***We are as children*** are flamboyantly poetic, unsuitable for most contexts). The construction ***A is to B as C is to D*** is very specific *(A relates to B **in the same way that** C relates to D)*, and probably shouldn't be linked to simpler forms.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for your explanation. What do you think is a proper way to use this phrase to answer a question like "What is the difference between Java and JavaScript"? Is it possible I can directly answer:"Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster"? Or do you recommend other ways?

Comment: "Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster" would be a perfectly idiomatic response to a slightly different question: "How is Java like JavaScript" or "What's the connection between Java and JavaScript."  A good answer to "What is the difference between Java and JavaScript" might be: "Don't be misled by their similar names.  Java and JavaScript are as different as ham and hamster"

Comment: @Juhasz Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I suggest that you should post on [ell.se] if you prefer anything to 1.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I didn’t mean “Men are as women”  is a meaningful parse.  I took OP to mean he was looking for the pure “subject verb” essence.  For example “Suzy sat in the tree with Joe” boils down to “Suzy sat”.   Here the first clause boils down to “A is” in the same way I might say “I am”.  And the second clause is thus “C is”  thus the compound is “A ***is*** [just] as C ***is***”.   And not OP’s parse of “something as something”